# truncate UTF8 words in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, truncate

I'm using this code to cut sentence into first 3 words but it does not work with utf8 characters.

```
function truncateWords($input, $numwords, $padding="")
{
   $output = strtok($input, " \n");
   while(--$numwords > 0) $output .= " " . strtok(" \n");
   if($output != $input) $output .= $padding;
   return $output;
}
```

I need some help to make it cut utf8 characters too.

for example: "I need some help to make it cut" >> "I need some"

but does not work with utf8  "Thách Thức Danh Hài 4" im expecting result like "Thách Thức Danh"

Comment: You should include an example of the input string, what you're getting and what you expect to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop to do this, you can simply use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
<?php
$str = 'Thách Thức Danh Hài 4';

//Thách Thức Danh
echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $str), 0, 3));
```

https://3v4l.org/6be5S